# C# - How can I export a list to a spreadsheet faster?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a program that calls the following method below, which simply exports a list to an Excel spreadsheet.  The majority of the program's runtime is spent executing this method once.  In my last run, this method took 5 minutes and 50 seconds to execute, on a list of size ~46,000.  Can you give any suggestions on how I can improve my code to make this method run faster?  I don't feel that this should take roughly 6 minutes to execute...but the only thing that sticks out to me is that there may be a more efficient way to export a list to a spreadsheet column, without iterating through rows using the dummy integer variable "i", and copying one string at a time to the column.

```
       public static string ExportListToSpreadsheet(string xlwbk, string xlwksht, List<string> tagnamelist)
    {
        var watch = new Stopwatch();
        watch.Start();
        object misValue = Refl.Missing.Value;
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        Excel.Worksheet xlsheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets.Add();
        xlsheet.Name = xlwksht;
        int i = 1;

        foreach(string tagname in tagnamelist)
        {
                xlsheet.Cells[i,1].Value = tagname;
                i += 1;
        }

        string filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\" + xlwbk;
        xlWorkbook.SaveAs(filename, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue,
        misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        watch.Stop();
        return watch.Elapsed.ToString();

    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The fastest way I know is to use the OpenXML SDK, but drop down into the XML API (rather than the object API) for doing the actual cell data.  There are posts on the internet on how to do this (sorry, it's been 5 plus years (and 3 jobs ago)) since I did this - I don't have the details handy

Comment: https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Comment: Note on EPPlus ... EPPlus will from version 5 switch license from LGPL to Polyform Noncommercial 1.0.0 license.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the ClosedXML library a try. I've put DataTables that have tens of thousands of rows into a spreadsheet and it takes like 10 seconds.

For a list you just simply do this:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
..
var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("myData");
ws.Cell(1, 1).InsertData(tagnamelist);
wb.SaveAs(@"c:\..\tagnamelist.xlsx");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  Execution time went from ~6m to 1 second.

Comment: Yeah, I love that library. It's almost too easy.

Comment: If just writing you can also specify XLEventTracking.Disabled in the XLWorkbook ctor

Answer (score -1):

Not an answer specific to C#, but to any scripting/automation: writing the Excel cells one at a time is terribly inefficient, instead define a Range and set the data all in one hit. Define a 2D array of variants that matches the layout of the data you want, then reference a Range object of the same size in Excel, and set the data.

I put the VBA example as it is easy to test, and I am not familiar with how C# creates arrays (maybe a 2D array of objects). In VBA the ".Value" on the Range is redundant, but might be needed in C#.

```
Sub WriteBigData()
    Dim vData() As Variant

    Dim lValues As Long
    lValues = 10000

    'Create a 2D array matching the size of your data
    ReDim vData(1 To lValues, 1 To 1) As Variant
    
    'Fill this temporary array with your data 
    'Just simple numbers in this example
    For n = 1 To lValues
        vData(n, 1) = n
    Next n

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1").Resize(lValues, 1)

    'This sets all the values of the range in one hit
    'with no costly iteration
    rng.Value = vData
End Sub
```

Comment: I know youre trying to help, but seriously why would you use a language that OP didnt ask for? This is a bad answer.

Comment: @DarthScitus Because the Excel object model and the COM interface are the same, as is the principle of writing data in one hit rather than cell by cell.